# What's the best way to wrap Flash in a windows app that forces a specific screen resolution?

Tags: windows, flash

Can someone recommend a good solution for a Windows based wrapper around a Flash application(or even IE, in which I can call Flash), that would launch as an executable and force the screen to a specific resolution and then render the Flash in that (full screen) window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pre-packaged solution is to use [MDM Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/).  Its functionality includes the ability [control screen resolution](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files/MDM/MDM%20Zinc%203.0/help/System.setResolution%28%29.htm). Active resolution enforcement could probably be implemented with a simple listener for screen size changes.

Answer (score 0):

A customized launcher is usually the best. Use the Windows UI API to set a screen resolution, and then launch flash player from your wrapper.

If you don't have the skills to do this, you should contract the work to a C programmer. It should take approximately 100 lines of code or less.